# How build harfbuzz without dependencies

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, freetype, harfbuzz

I want build latest `harfbuzz-ng` library on Windows 7. But in build system by default I must go through long quest to gain: `ragel`, `pkg-config`, `gtkdocize` and other stuff. Even in the end if I get all what need for build system I get  errors (sorry cannot say which concrete errors), last time I tried to build this library 2 month ago). Maybe on Linux system it is easy to get and build all this stuff but on Windows always something doesn't want to be compiled. Or the problem is that I don't find instructions which guide me on Windows, only Linux.

**What I want to get is simple instructions how build only `harfbuzz-ng` with `freetype` dependency** (and maybe add `ICU`) by `MinGW` compiler on Windows.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Thank you @Racil for revision now question looks better. And sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't worry about your English; we are here to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone reading this, have a look at harfbuzz.cc in the project which makes you able to use harfbuzz without any build system, just include it in one of your sources, no build system is required, define HB_NO_MT or even HB_TINY (which brings a minimal harfbuzz) if you don't use harfbuzz in multithread mode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know i this is the answer you are looking for. I am trying to work with Harfbuzz as well and did this through several attempts which did not work out for various [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388899/harfbuzz-hb-shape-leads-to-access-violation).

One (old) example you could use as a starter is: [HarfBuzz static lib](http://www.readytext.co.uk/?p=3062). The .lib-file generated works with UCDN and just needs this file plus a source for the Freetype-functions to provide the necessary FT_Face-parameter (i did this by compiling another .lib via the freetype-sourcecode (freetype.org/download.html).

But I am unsure if this will work out for the MinGW-compiler (you don't use VC++ as IDE do you??).

Answer (score 1):

You may find of interest the MSYS2 build system. It is essentially a linux-style packaging system built on top of Windows(TM). You can download and install binary packages with simple commands (including automatic dependency solving). If you want to download a source package you can do that as well. http://msys2.github.io

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is very useful, but i cannot accept it, because i stop working on that project and not have time to test it. Sorry.